# Codeigniter: proper way to access function on custom library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create simple library called **Xauth.php** to check if user already login or not:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Xauth
{
  protected $ci;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
  }

  public function is_logged_in()
  {
    if ($this->ci->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

I put that library in my Admin_Controller, so whatever controller extended with Admin_Controller will be checked first, if the session data is empty they will be redirect to login page. And this is my **Admin_Controller.php**:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->load->library('Xauth');

    if ($this->Xauth->is_logged_in() == false) {
      redirect('auth');
    }
  }

}
```

But I got an errors, it says:

```
Message: Undefined property: Dashboard::$Xauth
```

Where is my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use your class with lowercase letters :

```
$this->xauth->is_logged_in()
```